# What is the safe PostScript expression to plot 1/floor(1/x)?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

What is the safe PostScript expression to plot `f(x)=1/floor(1/x)`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{/inv {dup 0 eq {pop e30} {1 exch div} ifelse} bind def}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{-1}{4}{x inv floor inv}% plotting f(x)=1/floor(1/x)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For every complex problem, there is a solution that is simple, neat, but wrong.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by `safe`? It is not clear to me, what you are asking for. Especially with your comments to the existing answers.

Comment: @Christoph: "save" means the operator `inv` can handle division by zero smartly and mathematically.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction there is no general "mathematically" defined definition that will give finite values that can be plotted: _you_ must define the function that you want to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=4}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
\psaxes[Dx=0.5]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.1)(1.1,1.1)
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,VarStep,VarStepEpsilon=1.e-9]{-1.5}{-0.001}{ 1/floor(1/x) }
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,VarStep,VarStepEpsilon=1.e-9]{0.001}{1}{ 1/floor(1/x) }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and plotted as a "function"

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\makeatletter
\def\doqp@line{ 2 copy CP Pyth2 1 gt { moveto }{ L } ifelse }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=4}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
\psaxes[Dx=0.5]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.1)(1.1,1.1)
\psset{algebraic,linecolor=red,VarStep,VarStepEpsilon=1.e-9,linewidth=1.5pt}
\psplot{-1.5}{-0.001}{ 1/floor(1/x) }
\psplot{0.001}{1}{ 1/floor(1/x) }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I will be nice if the vertical lines are not drawn.

Answer (score 5):

Your inv definition didn't appear to be in scope so I just inlined a similar definition

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{/inv {dup 0 eq {pop e30} {1 exch div} ifelse} bind def}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{-1}{4}
{1 1 x 0 eq {0.000001} {x} ifelse  div floor dup 0 eq {pop 0.000001} {} ifelse div}% plotting f(x)=1/floor(1/x)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction you asked for safe not correct:-) if x>1 floor(1/x) is 0 so 1/floor(1/x) is a bit arbitrary, what do you want it to do?

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction The function isn't defined over the specified domain so some mathematicians (including this one) would say that no output at all is an acceptable outcome. I changed the function to replace 0 by an arbitrary small value, if you want another outcome you need to specify the function at all values in the domain.

Answer (score 4):

It's `1 1 x div floor div`. I don't know if the  `floor`function is defined for algebraic notation in pstricks. Here is a code to plot this function with `pstricks` to be compiled with `pdflatex`; due to the infinite discontinuity in 0, you have to plot the two parts of the curve separately:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage[pdf, svgnames]{pstricks}%
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\myfunc{1 1 x div floor div}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 5cm, plotpoints = 1000}
\begin{pspicture}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
%\psplot[linecolor = VioletRed]{0.1}{1}{1 1 x div floor div}
\psset{linecolor = VioletRed}
\psplot[arrows = -*]{0.002}{1}{\myfunc}
\psplot[arrows = *-]{-1}{-0.002}{\myfunc}
\pscircle[linewidth = 0.25pt, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = white](0,0){0.8pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note : this isn't the real mathematical curve, as the vertical segments are not part of it. Plots obtained with `\psplot` are always `continuous` curves, which this one is not. Plotting the real curve would be more complex.

Comment: The domain is not complete. It must span from a negative x to a positive x.

Comment: In only gave the principle. My answer is updated.